# When are we going to get HTTPS only?

Tags: discussion, ssl

Serious question. I've been waiting for HTTPS for a long time. Nearly 24 months. Are there plans to move to HTTPS only for Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's a work in progress. Yes, we will have https by default at some point.